# missing content on server when deployed blazor ServerSide app

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, blazor

I deployed my Blazor server side App on my server.
Publish was OK, success.
But when I look on the repository where its published, I find lot of dll etc... but no content that I used to work with in local when I build the app...
All is working good, I access the web app from my browser, but as I use to work with some template personal files, they are missing on the server and the logic behind is lost...

how can I find back the files on the server where I publish my project and which the path I have to write in my code to update it?

I saw somewhere that I had to set the properties of each file that I need to have on my server ( build action -> Content ), I made it but still missing on server...

[image: My missing File example]

thanks.

Comment: Do you see the setting _immediately_ under the Build Action setting?  It is set to "Do not copy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your folder to `wwwroot`

[image]

Then on a razor page

```
<a href="Resources/Template/template.xlsx" download>Download File</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian Parker they are now not missing but the path seems not working...
`string fileName = "Ressources/Template/template.xlsx";` do i forget something?

Comment: @KhalidAb this is a relative path... The complete path would include the base url.

Comment: Thanks @BrianParker and we can add this link to understand how work path directory on server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411151/relative-path-not-working-when-website-is-deployed)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is what @David L in the comments underneath your post and @Brian MacKay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593227/cant-reach-file-in-wwwroot-when-project-is-deployed) have said:

You need to change the **Copy to output directory** to something other than **Do not copy**. For example to **Copy always**.